# In bivariate probability: How do I denote different cases at the same time?

Tags: probability, notation

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$, each of which can take on the values $1$ or $0$. I was browsing other questions for examples of notation, but couldn't find any. In particular I want to know how I can write down

> $P(X=1,Y=0)+P(X=0,Y=1)+P(X=1,Y=1)$

more concisely, besides $1-P(X=0,Y=0)$?

Comment: Do you mean "besides $1-P(X=0,Y=1)$"? If so, how about "$P((X-1)Y\neq 0)$"?

Comment: You mean $1-P(X=0,Y=1)$ ? This is a notation I would use too.

Comment: @MPW Sorry, a typo, so there is no general common way of doing that?

Comment: @callculus fixed

Comment: @TanzWalzer $P(X,Y>0)$ would be an alternative notation.

Comment: @callculus I chose a bad example, the key is that I want to be able to include as many different combinations of variable outcomes as wanted, just with shorter notation.

Comment: @TanzWalzer In general: The more different cases you have the less can be summarized. One simplification is to use the converse probability as you did.